# Simplifying looooong expressions. Any tools out there?

Tags: c, formatting

I am working on this brain numbing task where I have to simplify loooooong expressions like this:

```
coef = ((((((((((inv_nrg >> 16) * (int)((short)nl)) + (((inv_nrg & 0x0000FFFF) * (int)((short)nl)) >> 16)))) + ((inv_nrg * ((16 == 1 ? (nl >> 1) + (nl & 1) : ((nl >> 15) + 1) >> 1)))))) >> 16) * (int)((short)(1024 << 1))) + ((((((((((inv_nrg >> 16) * (int)((short)nl)) + (((inv_nrg & 0x0000FFFF) * (int)((short)nl)) >> 16)))) + ((inv_nrg * ((16 == 1 ? (nl >> 1) + (nl & 1) : ((nl >> 15) + 1) >> 1)))))) & 0x0000FFFF) * (int)((short)(1024 << 1))) >> 16));
  }
```

There must be a tool out there which can take the above expression, chew on it and spit out a more clean and simple expression?

Please help me - my brain is going numb!!!

Comment: Put it in an IDE that can highlight the matching pairs of parentheses.

Comment: Holy moly! That's a bit messy...

Comment: Looks like somebody expanded a macro in your code, or somebody was insane while writing it, otherwise the checks for `16 == 1` make very little sense.

Comment: Make a function out of it: `int mystery(inv_ngr, nl) { ... return coef;}` compile it with optimizations and disassemble it. (Have to probably guess a few good constants.)

Comment: Yes. Using macros without any thought is insane!!!! That's what I'm dealing with here...insanity!!

Answer (score 2):

Break it down into sections (and let the compiler worry about optimising it)

For example, you can assign `inv_nrg >> 16` to a variable `inv_nrg_high`. The same for `inv_nrg & 0x0000ffff` as `inv_nrg_low`

Some numeric constants can also be simplified - (1024 << 1) can be replaced with the actual value.

There are also some "dead" expressions in there `(16 == 1? stuff1 : stuff2 )` can be replaced with `stuff2` because 16 is NEVER equal to 1.

I'll let you do the donkey-work of actually removing all the superfluous parenthesis and replacing the variables. It's entirely possible and I've worked my way through most of it just to see what it does [makes no sense to me, but never mind].

Edit: Having spent a few minutes, I came up with this:

```
int inv_nrg_high = inv_nrg >> 16;
int inv_nrg_low  = inv_nrg & 0xFFFF;
int nl_sh_p1_sh     = ((nl >> 15) + 1) >> 1;
int x = ((inv_nrg_high * nl)) + ((inv_nrg_low * nl)) >> 16;
int y = (x + inv_nrg * nl_sh_p1_sh);

coef = ((y >> 16) * 2048) + ((y & 0x0000FFFF) * 2048) >> 16);
```

[I'm not 100% sure it's correct, but it's not that far off.

[It looks like soemthing that came out of a C preprocessor, and is probably the result of some complicated fixed point math or something like that]

Comment: You're right in everything you said. It's the output from a pre-processor. I'm cleaning it up first, and then I'm going to optimize the code (using intrinsic functions). What would really help me during this clean-up process is if I had a tool that could simplify the expressions I encounter during this task...Or else I have to do it manually (like you just did) for 100s of these mind-numbing expressions..

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way than to do it manually. Of course, you could probably attack the macros in the first place to produce something a bit more readable!

Comment: The problem is that the original programmer used these macros without any thought or consideration what the code actually expands to. Totally insane!

Comment: Yes, so if you modify the macros to generate temporary variables and use that as your stepping stone, you should be able to make much more progress in decoding AFTER pre-rpocessor.